# Is AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener supported in Android version 2.1?

Tags: android-2.1-eclair

As per the title, is AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener supported in Android version 2.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is **no**. The long one is here:

See the official Android Reference for [AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html) right on the top stands `Since:`[`API Level 8`](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html). If you look to [Android API Level](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html) which is linked there too you will see that this interface exists since Android 2.2.x.